# why one of my dependency's maven coordinates in pom file changed follow the new project's maven coordinates

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have created a maven archetype from a project, in this project's pom file, there's an dependency demo-admin

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-admin</artifactId>
    <version>${demo-admin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

this dependency is installed in my local repository.

But when I checked the generated archetype files, the pom.xml file in the archetype-resources folder, the dependency looks as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${rootArtifactId}-admin</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

so every times I create a new project from the archetype, the maven coordinates of this denpendency will change.

Anybody has the same issue?

**EDIT:**
This issue could be reproduced as below steps:

1. create a project which GAV as below

```
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-admin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
```

2. create a project which GAV as below

```
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
```

3. the second project contains a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-admin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

4. create an archetype from the second project using the command below
   a. cd abc
   b. mvn clean
   c. mvn archetype:create-from-project
5. go the "abc/target/generated-sources/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources" folder, you can see a pom file, in the pom file, the dependency looks as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${rootArtifactId}-admin</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

so, if I create a new project based on the abc archetype, when I input different GAV, the dependency will also changed based on the input values

Comment: What do you mean by a "maven coordinator"?

Comment: @JFabianMeier groupid, artifactid and version

Comment: The reason is that you have given placeholders in your project which is the usual way to do ... If you like to keep the GAV of that don't put placeholders in there ....

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, the placeholder is in the dependency's GAV, but this is just a dependency, not an archetype project, so I don't want it to have a placeholder there.

Comment: Do not put the placeholders in the template...

Comment: @khmarbaise I know, the template is generated by maven, I run "mvn archetype:create-from-project" to generate the template, I don't want the dependency's content contains placeholder

Comment: @Allen4Tech So why don't you just do what I told you already twice?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the automatic replacement of your of the groupId and artifactId of your demo project by placeholders.

Either give you demo project some name that never appears anywhere else or edit the resulting archetype by replacing the placeholders with the correct values.

Comment: do you mean, the project which my archetype created from should have a name that doesn't exist in the dependency pom's GAV?

Comment: For more details, the dependency's groupid is as same as the archetype project's groupid, and the dependency's artifactid is demo-admin, the archetype project's artifactid is demo, any impact of it?

Comment: Just call the project/artifactId `muesli` and the groupId `with.milk.and.sugar` and you will probably not have these problems.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier, so this is the maven issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Hi @J Fabian Meier, thanks for your kindly reply. Please check my edit version, the steps can reproduce the issue

Comment: As I said: Use a groupId and artifactId that does not appear in your dependencies.